# Using PHP to save smooth jSignature image?

Tags: javascript, php, image, vector, svg

I need to submit signature data to be converted to an image.  I'm using [jSignature](http://willowsystems.github.io/jSignature/#/about/) to capture the signature, and submitting the `base30` data to the server.  On the server, I use [their PHP script](https://github.com/willowsystems/jSignature/tree/master/extras/SignatureDataConversion_PHP) to convert the data and save it to a png.  The problem is, the image is not smooth at all.  Exporting as SVG makes really smooth lines, but exporting the data directly to a PNG makes it look like the picture below.  It's a small pic on this question, but if you open it you can see it's far worse quality from the smoothed out lines that the SVG export provides.

Is there a way to export the image to a PNG so that it is smooth?  Or somehow convert SVG to PNG?  I think this would have to be done without Imagick, though.

[image]

```
        $signature = new jSignature_Tools_Base30();
        $sig_a = $signature->Base64ToNative($user_signature);
                    //$user_signature is the base30 data
        $sig_im = imagecreatetruecolor(1295, 328);
        imagesavealpha($sig_im, true);
        $sig_trans_colour = imagecolorallocatealpha($sig_im, 0, 0, 0, 127);
        imagefill($sig_im, 0, 0, $sig_trans_colour);
        imagesetthickness($sig_im, 5);

        $sig_black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

        for ($i = 0; $i<count($a); $i++) {
            for ($j = 0; $j<count($a[$i]['x']); $j++) {
                if ( ! isset($a[$i]['x'][$j]) or ! isset($a[$i]['x'][$j+1])) break;
                imageline($im, $a[$i]['x'][$j], $a[$i]['y'][$j], $a[$i]['x'][$j+1], $a[$i]['y'][$j+1], $black);
            }
        }

        //Then I use imagepng() to export
```